# how to push object inside array laravel php

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

i did query from db and return array

```
$games = Game::where('admin_id', $user->id)->where('active', true)->get();
```

now i am trying to add object inside `$games` array like this

```
$games->push(['name' => 'Game1', 'color' => 'red']); //its adding array instead object
```

please explain Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you pushed an `array`, so it is adding array.

```php
// here, you are pushing the array so you get the array.
['name' => 'Game1', 'color' => 'red']
```

Pushing the object like this:

```php
$games = $games->push(new Game(['name' => 'Game1', 'color' => 'red']));
```

or this way:

```php
$games = $games->push((object)['name' => 'Game1', 'color' => 'red']);
```

Comment: i don't want to save to db i just want to add inside array variable

Comment: @sidheart there is nothing related saving into db? where did you get it from?

Comment: @sidheart using eloquent model does not mean saving into db.

Comment: That is the problem i am facing that i have collection get from db and i want to add 2 more object inside array variable that i can use it like `$game->name` later

Comment: @sidheart my answer did exactly what you wanted, the two solutions I provided are not updating db at all. I do not understand what are you worrying about.

Comment: ohh thanks this `$games = $games->push((object)['name' => 'Game1', 'color' => 'red']);` works fine thank you